# Jaeger UI group axon events

Tags: java, events, axon, jaeger

I have a spring boot application with several microservices. There are about 100+ different events. And I wanted to see in convenient UI to see sequence of them.

I googled about Jaeger UI, ran it via docker container and everything works almost fine, except one important thing, events are not grouped, I just see multiple independent events.

I give 2 examples,
First: how I want it to see
Second: how I see.

Thanks for any suggestions.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.axonframework.extensions.tracing</groupId>
    <artifactId>axon-tracing-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
    <version>4.4</version>
    </dependency>
<dependency>
   <groupId>io.opentracing.contrib</groupId>
   <artifactId>opentracing-spring-jaeger-web-starter</artifactId>
   <version>3.2.2</version>
</dependency>



services:
  axon:
    image: axoniq/axonserver
    hostname: axon
    ports:
      - "8024:8024"
      - "8124:8124"
      - "8224:8224"

    jaeger:
        image: jaegertracing/all-in-one:1.7
        container_name: jaegertracing
        ports:
          - "16686:16686"
          - "6831:6831/udp"
          - "6832:6832/udp"
        networks:
          - axonnet
          - default
```

networks:
axonnet:
driver: bridge

[image: How I want to see]

[image: How I currently see]

Comment: Do you use a Command Gateway to send your commands? Only the Command/Query Gateway instances get instrumented by default.

Comment: Sure, I send commands with graphql to Command Gateway. As you can see on second screenshot I have some events they was followed by commands. The main thing I want to see is grouping events to one group, that they was followed after each other

Comment: I've quite recently heard a similar predicament from a different user. You might have spotted a bug here Vladimir, although at this stage I am not entirely sure yet. Would you be up for opening an issue, potentially providing a small sample project showing the problem occurring persistently? FYI, here's the link to construct issues for Axon's Tracing Extension -> https://github.com/AxonFramework/extension-tracing/issues/new/choose